# Java String character Pattern

Tags: java, match

How to check if string consists of letters only by using regular expression.
I know how to check only one character: `if (s.matches("\\w")) System.out.println(true);`
But I don`t understand how to check full string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `matches("\\w")` with `matches("^[A-Za-z]*$")`. This should instruct the matcher to expect the string to be made up entirely of 0 or more letters (case insensitive).

The `*` denotes zero or more repetitions of what preceeds it. On the other hand, the `+` expects at least one instance of whatever it is that preceeds it, thus, the `*` operator can potentially match an empty string, which I do not know if it is something which you are after.

Answer (score 3):

`\w` includes numbers in its expression. You could do

```
if (s.matches("[a-zA-Z]*")) {
  ...
}
```

where `*` matches 0 or more characters. Note that empty strings are matched by this pattern also so you may want to use the `+` quantifier instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex matching `[a-zA-Z]` instead, of looking for the single character `w`, and add the `+` to specify you want all characters.

Something like:

```
System.out.println(s1.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));
```

should do the trick.